# How do I modify my PHP query to get back the info I want?

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a table in HTML, whose rows are populated via PHP using the content in a database. The issue I'm struggling with is that I need to go back and reference each individual variable that is spit out, but I'm not sure how to do it.

**Scenario**

Here's an sample of the code:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Supplier</th>

<?php
$supplierQuery    = "SELECT * FROM allparts WHERE partNumber = '$q'" ;
$supplierResult     = mysqli_query($con, $supplierQuery);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($supplierResult)) {
  $supplier     = $row['supplier'];
  }
$popupQuery     = "SELECT * FROM $supplier" ;
$popupResult      = mysqli_query($con, $popupQuery);

?>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')"><?= $supplier ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Let's say that when `$supplierResult` runs, it generates a table that looks like this:

```
Supplier
a
b
c
d
```

The popup that's triggered from the `<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">` code is supposed to supply information back to the user, but **right now, regardless of the supplier I click on, it's giving me information on `d` and I'm not sure why it's doing this.**

Here is the code that runs when the user clicks on the hyperlink:

```
<!-- Start pop-up -->
  <div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
  <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;"">
  <a href="#"" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')"><img src="/img/close.png"></a>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Supplier</h2>
  <table>
  <thead>
  <th style="text-align: center;">NAME</th>
  <th style="text-align: center;">ADDRESS</th>  
  </thead>
  <?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($popupResult)) {
    $popupName      = $row['supplierName'];
    $popupAddress   = $row['supplierAddress'];    

  ?>  
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $popupName ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $popupAddress ?></td>  
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <?php  
  }  
  ?>
  </table>
  </div>
<!-- End popup section -->
```

Obviously, each time someone clicks on a supplier, `$supplier`'s value is `d`, but I can't figure out why this is.

**Question:**

How do I modify my php query, or the position of the popup query to ensure that each popup provides data back on the correct supplier?

Would it be possible to modify the popup query into an array, so that each of the 4 rows is actually a unique value instead of each one being populated with `d`?

**Update: popup.js**

```
function toggle(div_id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
    else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}
function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
        blanket_height = viewportheight;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
        } else {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
    var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
    blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-150;//150 is half popup's height
    popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
}
function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
        window_width = viewportwidth;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
        } else {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
        }
    }
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    window_width=window_width/2-150;//150 is half popup's width
    popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
}
function popup(windowname) {
    blanket_size(windowname);
    window_pos(windowname);
    toggle('blanket');
    toggle(windowname);     
}
```

Comment: The whole loop overwrites $supplier  each time so **d**, being the last in the loop before carrying on with the rest of the page, is what $supplier is.

Comment: Yup - so the table generates 4 rows, but when I launch the popup, the query is finished and $supplier = `d`.  That part I get - I don't know how to make it so that each instance of the popup references the specific supplier I've click on though....

Comment: **while(whatever){echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="popup(\'popUpDiv\')">'.$supplier.'</a></td>'; }** You'll need to show us the popup script if you need help there too.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've added the script as well.   I didn't write it, and JavaScript isn't my forte, so I'm a bit iffy still on how it all works.

Comment: Ok, couldn't you ask the author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the variable $supplier is set to the last row in query in your main script - your popup is called AFTER that - so of course you always just get the last row's supplier.

You can either reset your query (which row-counter points to the last entry - or you can modify your javascript function so it takes the supplier as value in the theader -> popup('popupDiv','$supplier')

Comment: sorry that my answer is not useful - still, it is right :-)

Comment: Sorry - I didn't see this until I refreshed the window.  Thank you for your response.  I understand that the PHP query is running on the server-side, and only AFTER it executes does my JavaScript initiate the call to create the popup, and that is why $supplier is always `d`.  What I don't understand is how to call popup each time to populate it with the correct supplier from that line.  This seems like the most straight-forward approach.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this kind of problem.
You could include an ajax request in your javascript or write the name & adress of the suppliers in an javascript array while reading it the first time.
Or - not most performant but perfect if someone changes the database while visitors check the site - you can make a second request on the database when opening the popup.

And of course - you can reset the pointer: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

Comment: Yeah, AJAX could totally work in this situation.  I'm not familiar with data seek, but I will read up on it too.  Thanks!  Ugh, now I have to go write things in JavaScript - not my favorite thing ever! :)